# How to stop automactic execution of SEQUENCE 1 in CSS Police Light Bar?

Tags: jquery

In the Code Pen CSS Police Light Bar example, the code automatically runs sequence 1. How to stop this?

[link to the code pen example](https://codepen.io/drew_mc/pen/EVXvaJ)

Here is the js from the example:

```
$('#default').on('click', function(){
  $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('#light-1, #light-2, #light-3').attr('class', 'light strobe blue');
  $('#light-4, #light-5, #light-6').attr('class', 'light strobe red delay');
}, 50);

});

$('#alt').on('click', function(){
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#light-1, #light-3, #light-5').attr('class', 'light strobe blue');
  $('#light-2, #light-4, #light-6').attr('class', 'light strobe red delay');
  }, 50);

});

$('#spotlight').on('click',function(){
  if( $('#default.active, #alt.active ,#off.active').length > 0 ){

    if( !$(this).is('.active') ) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('#light-3, #light-4').attr('class', 'light');
      $('#light-3, #light-4').addClass('spotlight');
    } else if ( $(this).is('.active') && $('#default.active').length > 0 ){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#light-1, #light-2, #light-3').attr('class', 'light strobe blue');
        $('#light-4, #light-5, #light-6').attr('class', 'light strobe red delay');
}, 10);
    } else if ( $(this).is('.active') && $('#alt.active').length > 0 ){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#light-1, #light-3, #light-5').attr('class', 'light strobe blue');
        $('#light-2, #light-4, #light-6').attr('class', 'light strobe red delay');
  }, 10);
    } else if ( $(this).is('.active') && $('#off.active').length > 0 ){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
    }

  } else {
    alert('Spotlight is not for use with "Traffic Warnings" because these light sequences are meant to simlulate the view from the rear of the vehicle. :(')
  }
})

$('#off').on('click', function(){
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
})

$('#traffic-default').on('click', function(){
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.light').attr('class', 'light');
  $('#light-1').attr('class', 'light strobe blue');
  $('#light-2, #light-3, #light-4, #light-5').attr('class', 'light warn on');
  $('#light-6').attr('class', 'light strobe red delay');
})

$('#caution').on('click', function(){
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.light').attr('class', 'light caution');
})

$('#warn-left').on('click', function(){
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.light').attr('class', 'light warn left');
})

$('#warn-right').on('click', function(){
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.light').attr('class', 'light warn right');
})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial sequence is not playing because of jQuery but actually due to the classes on each element. The animations are class dependant so the classes set in the HTML on load will play the the corresponding animation.

For example the left most light (`<div id="light-1" class="light strobe blue">...</div>`) has the classes `light strobe blue`. If you remove `strobe blue` it won't play the animation on load.

You can stop the initial animation on load by removing all the classes from each `div#light-(1,2,3...etc)` element except the for `light` class.

See this updated JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4jrhbfgx/